# How to Join 3 Tabels in Sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to join 3 tables all together but when I execute the query only the first row on the table is displayed. The table consists of many rows. How can I display multiple rows?

This is the code that I tried

```
SELECT
l.id,m.name,b.bookname,l.issuedate,l.returndate
FROM lend l
INNER JOIN member m
    on l.memberid = m.id 
INNER JOIN books b ON b.id = l.bookid
```

Member table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2fS4.jpg)

Books table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GAVi.jpg)

lend table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyJqI.jpg)

data i need to join

**ID membername  Bookname issue_date  return_date**

Comment: the syntax is correct...if you have an issue, it's because the data on those tables isn't matching

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results

Comment: I'm going to assume it is because you are querying from Lend first. Instead, query from Member first (change lend with member), and change your joins to LEFT joins. If you have a multiple members, but only 1 member is in the lend table, you will get 1 row returned with INNER joins.

Comment: sir i have update above. i written tables  member,book,lend then how to join

Comment: But you didn't post any data or expected results.

Comment: i will post the data sir

Comment: A lend can't exist without a book and a member. Can you do inner join between lend and book and see result. Then do inner join between lend and member and see the result. You'll find the issue. I guess id references between tables have some problems.

Comment: sir can write query sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my first post.

It is possible that one of the other tables that you have joined to does not contain the other 2 records. In order to see all records from [lend], you would do this:

```
SELECT l.id, m.name, b.bookname, l.issuedate, l.returndate 
FROM lend l 
LEFT OUTER JOIN member m ON l.memberid = m.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN books b ON b.id = l.bookid
```

I am not sure which table contains the records that you are interested in, but select from only that table first. Check the record count. Then LEFT OUTER JOIN to one more table. Execute. Check record count. Keep going. That way you know which table join has affected the record count.

Comment: sir i edited above sir. all table i written above along with data. i tried your query sir but name colum secord row null

Answer (score 0):

if  you want all records of all tables:

```
SELECT
l.id,m.name,b.bookname,l.issuedate,l.returndate
FROM lend l
FULL OUTER JOIN member m
    on l.memberid = m.id 
FULL OUTER JOIN books b ON b.id = l.bookid
```

if you wand only records that are related with lend:

```
SELECT
l.id,m.name,b.bookname,l.issuedate,l.returndate
FROM lend l
left JOIN member m
    on l.memberid = m.id 
left JOIN books b ON b.id = l.bookid
```